# How to use wdiff with diff as input?

Tags: unix, diff

I am using wdiff to diff two files and I am trying to use the "-d --diff-input" option so I can stream in from a unified diff as the document.  Imagine the following two text files:

one.txt: `My hovercraft is full of eeels.`

two.txt: `My hovercraft is full of slippery eels.`

(The -123 is to suppress diff output and the -s for stats.)

If I do `wdiff -s123 one.txt two.txt` I get:

```
one.txt: 6 words  5 83% common  0 0% deleted  1 17% changed
two.txt: 7 words  5 71% common  0 0% inserted  2 29% changed
```

This is what I'd expect. However, if I do: `diff one.txt two.txt | wdiff -s123d` I get:

```
(null): 17 words  16 94% common  1 6% deleted  0 0% changed
(null): 16 words  16 100% common  0 0% inserted  0 0% changed
```

From what I can tell of the docs and googling, this is the intended use case and they should return the same output, but obviously not.  Anyone know what I am missing?

EDIT:  I am using wdiff 1.1.2 on mint/ubuntu.

EDIT:

I missed the word "unified" in the man page.  It is looking for the "-u" option, so I should be specifying `diff -u one.txt two.txt | wdiff -s123d`.  I get better results, but unfortunately unified diff still has a two line header which gets diff'd.

```
(null): 15 words  11 73% common  0 0% deleted  4 27% changed
(null): 16 words  11 69% common  0 0% inserted  5 31% changed
```

So now the problem is how to get diff to not emit the header lines.  Again I have googled and experimented with no results.  If course I could write a little script to rip off the three lines before wdiff, hopefully it will still parse.

On a side note, because it used the unified diff output, it should work with git diff output a well.

Comment: It reads like a bug; which is possible. None of the test suite code for wdiff actually checks that the statistics are correct when run in that mode.

Comment: I didn't look at the test code, good idea!  I just assumed I was doing something wrong.